# Format-List: sort properties by name

Tags: sorting, powershell

Is it possible to sort the output of the Format-List cmdlet by property name?
Suppose that I have an object $x with two properties "A" and "B", and when I run Format-List with it I get

```
(PS) > $x | Format-List
B : value b
A : value a
```

I would like to have

```
(PS) > $x | Format-List 
A : value a
B : value b
```

**NOTE**: I should have specified from the beginning that, unlike in the example with "A" and "B" properties, the real object I have to deal with has quite a lot of properties, and new ones could be added in the future, so I don't know all the property names in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, `Format-List` does not provide such an option.

For your particular example this should work:

```
$x | Select-Object A, B | Format-List
```

If the property set is not fixed/known then the procedure will be more tricky with use of `Get-Member` and some preprocessing making sorted parameter array for `Select-Object`.

EDIT:

Here it is (let's use $host instead of $x):

```
$host | Select-Object ([string[]]($host | Get-Member -MemberType Property | %{ $_.Name } | Sort-Object)) | Format-List
```

**Christopher** is right, `Select-Object` is not absolutely needed:

```
$host | Format-List ([string[]]($host | Get-Member -MemberType Property | %{ $_.Name } | Sort-Object))
```

Comment: By using PowerShell command aliases, the above answer can be shortened to:
`$x | fl ([string[]]($x | gm -m Property | %{$_.Name} | sort))`

Answer (score 12):

Nothing wrong with the accepted answer, but a *really* quick-and-dirty option for a one-off—that doesn't require having the collection already in a variable—might be...

```
... | Format-List | Out-String -Stream | Sort-Object
```

...which does a sort on each line of the output of `Format-List`.

Note that any property values that go onto the next line will be broken (and probably appear at the top of the output), but this could be fixed by the slightly-less-memorable...

```
... | Format-List | Out-String -Stream -Width ([Int32]::MaxValue) | Sort-Object
```

...at the expense of column indentation.

Of course, all object/pipeline info is lost by that `Out-String` call, although—considering the same is true of `Format-List`—you probably aren't going to care by that point.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Christopher's idea, using `get-member` and `format-list -Property`:

```
$x | fl -property ($x| gm | sort name).name
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've created a function that can be added to your PowerShell profile and then use by piping an object to it. [Here is a link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/asheroto/e589f10e8c31ba4bab3776e27f4e3de3).

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can think of is to create a new psobject based off the old one but with the properties sorted e.g.:

```
$x | %{$obj = new-object psobject; `
       $_.psobject.properties | Sort Name | `
           %{Add-Member -Inp $obj NoteProperty $_.Name $_.Value}; $obj} | fl
```

You could get fancier and give the new psobject a typename that matches the old one, etc.

Comment: I like this solution too... +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a small number of properties, you can specify their order with the -Property parameter.

Here is an example:

```
Format-List -Property Owner, Path
```

If you have a lot of properties, I am not sure there is any easy way to sort them in Format-List, like Roman said.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work OK (edited so it accepts pipeline input):

```
function Format-SortedList
{
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Object]$InputObject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Switch]$Descending
    )

    process
    {
        $properties = $InputObject | Get-Member -MemberType Properties

        if ($Descending) {
            $properties = $properties | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending
        }

        $longestName = 0
        $longestValue = 0

        $properties | ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.Name.Length -gt $longestName) {
                $longestName = $_.Name.Length
            }

            if ($InputObject."$($_.Name)".ToString().Length -gt $longestValue) {
                $longestValue = $InputObject."$($_.Name)".ToString().Length * -1
            }
        }

        Write-Host ([Environment]::NewLine)

        $properties | ForEach-Object { 
            Write-Host ("{0,$longestName} : {1,$longestValue}" -f $_.Name, $InputObject."$($_.Name)".ToString())
        }
    }
}

$Host, $MyInvocation | Format-SortedList
$Host, $MyInvocation | Format-SortedList -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel sure that you can achieve the desired output. I suggest that you experiment with both Sort-Object (or plain Sort) and also Group-Object (plain Group)

My idea is to place the sort, or group before | format-list

Thus $x | sort-object -property xyz | Format-List

Comment: This approach will sort the objects based on the value of property xyz but it won't sort the poperties for each individual object.

Answer (score 0):

By using `Select-Object` with a calculated property (`@{}`) and then excluding it (`-ExcludeProperty`) you can also order the properties as you want. This works even when you don't know what's coming upfront.

```bsh
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color   = 'Green'
        Type    = 'Fruit'
        Name    = 'kiwi'
        Flavour = 'Sweet'
    }
) | Select-Object @{Name = 'Flavour'; Expression = { $_.Flavour } },
@{Name = 'Name'; Expression = { $_.Name } }, * -ExcludeProperty Name, Flavour |
Format-List
```

**Output:**

```bsh
Flavour : Sweet
Name    : kiwi
Color   : Green
Type    : Fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I add my variation on the answer of Roman Kuzmin here.

I use disks in my example. Start with:

```
Get-Disk|Select-Object FriendlyName,SerialNumber
$CIMInstance=Get-Disk -SerialNumber A1B2C3D4E5
$DiskNumber=$CIMInstance.DiskNumber
```

The following may look familiar

```
$Partition=Get-Partition -DiskNumber $DiskNumber      
foreach($P in $Partition){$P|Format-List -Property $($P|Get-Member -MemberType Property|Sort-Object Name).Name}
```

Now, use Select-Object to get all properties

```
$Partition=$(Get-Partition -DiskNumber $DiskNumber|Select-Object *) 
foreach($P in $Partition){$P|Format-List -Property $($P|Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty|Sort-Object Name).Name}
```

The Select-Object puts obejcts of type Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance in $Partition. These objects have NoteProperties instead of Properties.