# PSObject sorting

Tags: sorting, powershell

I am trying to format a PSObject related to a question a few days back. My object looks like this:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Version"= $winVersion.Caption
    "Processor Name" = $processorInfo.Name
    "Processor Manufacturer" = $processorInfo.Manufacturer
    "Processor Max Clock Speed" = $processorInfo.MaxClockSpeed     
} |format-list
```

The above gives the following output:

```
Processor Manufacturer    : GenuineIntel
Processor Max Clock Speed : 2201
Version                   : Microsoft Windows 8 Pro
Processor Name            : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
```

However, this:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Windows Version"= $winVersion.Caption
    "Processor Name" = $processorInfo.Name
    "Processor Manufacturer" = $processorInfo.Manufacturer
    "Processor Max Clock Speed" = $processorInfo.MaxClockSpeed     
} |format-list
```

gives the following output:

```
Processor Manufacturer    : GenuineIntel
Processor Max Clock Speed : 2201
Processor Name            : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
Windows Version           : Microsoft Windows 8 Pro
```

Not really a big deal, but I wonder why the formatting changes? It does not seem to be alphabetical in any way. Furthermore, I tried sorting the object with Sort-Object (from A-Z) but to no avail. Is it String related?

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3282208/1035521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of a `hashtable` can't be predicted ([in PowerShell V3.0 you can user the `[ordered]` accelerator to make an hashtable ordered](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2012/12/11/pshell-order.aspx)), but in V2.0 you need to build your custom object like this to preserve properties order:

```
$o = New-Object PSObject
 $o | add-member Noteproperty  "Version"  $winVersion.Caption
 $o | add-member Noteproperty  "Processor Name" $processorInfo.Name
 $o | add-member Noteproperty  "Processor Manufacturer" $processorInfo.Manufacturer
 $o | add-member Noteproperty  "Processor Max Clock Speed" $processorInfo.MaxClockSpeed

$o | format-list
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still add a custom method to your object to provide the format you want, for example:

```
$test = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Processor Manufacturer"="GenuineIntel"
    "Processor Max Clock Speed" = "2201"
    "Version"="Microsoft Windows 8 Pro"
}
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "show" -Value {echo $this.version;echo $this."processor manufacturer";echo $this."Processor Max Clock Speed"} -inputObject $test

$test.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
new-object psobject -property ([ordered]@{key1=$value1; key2=$value2})
```